# How to call a function, PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, function-call

I'm trying to use a function with PostgreSQL to save some data. Here is the create script:

```
-- Function: "saveUser"(integer, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying)

-- DROP FUNCTION "saveUser"(integer, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "saveUser"("pUserID" integer, "pName" character
varying, "pLastName" character varying, "pUserName" character varying, 
"pPassword" character varying, "peMail" character varying)
RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
SELECT 1
FROM "USERS"
WHERE "userID" = $1;

IF FOUND THEN
UPDATE "USERS" 
    SET     "name" = $2,
    "lastName" = $3,
    "userName" = $4,
    "password" = $5,
    "eMail" = $6
WHERE "userID" = $1;
ELSE
    INSERT INTO "USERS"
    ("name", "lastName", "userName", "password", "eMail")
    VALUES
        ($2, $3, $4, $5, $6);
END IF;
END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION "saveUser"(integer, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying) OWNER TO postgres;
```

PostreSQL Documentation states that to call a function which does not return any resultset, it is sufficient to write only its name and properties. So I try to call the function like this:

```
"saveUser"(3, 'asd','asd','asd','asd','asd');
```

But I get the error below:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""saveUser""
LINE 1: "saveUser"(3, 'asd','asd','asd','asd','asd')
     ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near ""saveUser""
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1
```

I have other functions which return a resultset. I use `SELECT * FROM "fnc"(...)` to call them and it works. Why am I getting this error?

---

**EDIT:** I am using pgAdmin III Query tool and trying to execute the SQL Statements there.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

The function call still should be a valid SQL statement:

```
SELECT "saveUser"(3, 'asd','asd','asd','asd','asd');
```

Comment: Using this, I get the error; "ERROR: query has no destination for result data". I wonder if this error has something to do with me wanting to return a boolean?

Comment: I tried this with another function which returns void and it works, but what if I wanted to return a boolean ?

Comment: Erkan: Tried combining the two answers? I.e. your invocation is wrong, and you're not returning anything for a function that is expected to return bool.

Moreover, why are you having mixed-case identifiers that you have to quote all the time?

Comment: @Alex: I declared the function to return boolean, and inserted 'RETURN 1=1;' at the bottom of the function, then used 'SELECT "saveUser"(..)' and it didn't work. I also tried to return void, remove 'RETURN 1=1', and use the same SELECT statement above, didn't work either.

Comment: The new error messaage you see ("ERROR: query has no destination for result data") refers to a bug in your function - the "SELECT" SQL statements in PL/pgSQL should always be "SELECT INTO". If you don't need the result use "PERFORM" (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT).

Comment: "...refers to a bug in your function...". That's it, instead of SELECT, I used PERFORM inside my function. Thanks Milen..

Answer (score 42):

For Postgresql you can use [PERFORM](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT). PERFORM is only valid within PL/PgSQL procedure language.

```
DO $$ BEGIN
    PERFORM "saveUser"(3, 'asd','asd','asd','asd','asd');
END $$;
```

The suggestion from the postgres team:

> HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.

Comment: I want to use SELECT instead of PERFOM inside do begin. If I use SELECT I am facing an error as [42601] ERROR: query has no destination for result data any idea why and I don't want to use INTO some variable because I am using pgtap funcation SELECT has_table('unit_test_output'); it should populate the output on the console

Answer (score 14):

We can have two ways of calling the functions written in pgadmin for postgre sql database.

Suppose we have defined the function as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION helloWorld(name text) RETURNS void AS $helloWorld$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    RAISE LOG 'Hello, %', name;
END;
$helloWorld$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

We can call the function helloworld in one of the following way:

```
SELECT "helloworld"('myname');

SELECT public.helloworld('myname')
```

Answer (score 7):

if your function does not want to return anything you should declare it to "return void" and then you can call it like this "perform functionName(parameter...);"

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue while trying to test a very similar function that uses a SELECT statement to decide if a INSERT or an UPDATE should be done.  This function was a re-write of a T-SQL stored procedure.
When I tested the function from the query window I got the error "query has no destination for result data".  I finally figured out that because I used a SELECT statement inside the function that I could not test the function from the query window until I assigned the results of the SELECT to a local variable using an INTO statement.  This fixed the problem.

If the original function in this thread was changed to the following it would work when called from the query window,

```
$BODY$
DECLARE
   v_temp integer;
BEGIN
SELECT 1 INTO v_temp
FROM "USERS"
WHERE "userID" = $1;
```

Answer (score -3):

you declare your function as returning boolean, but it never returns anything.

Comment: I inserted the line, 'RETURN 1=1' at the bottom of the function definition just to test this, did no good.

Comment: True, but the problem reported isn't caused by that.

Comment: Should be a comment (not answering the question)